# How do I reset column sort with Kendo UI Grid?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

[image]

I am trying to reset column sorting (see image above) so that there is no down or up arrow. 
I've tried `$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").refresh()` to redraw the grid but it doesn't unsort the column. Any thing else I can try beside refreshing my browser?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try:

```
$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.sort({});
```